# Multiple MySQL Table Query

Tags: php, mysql

I could not find an answer by searching as I am not sure what exactly it would be called what I'm searching for.

Anyways,  I have multiple tables in MySQL and am trying to "fill in" some of the final product.

```
myTable
id    assigned_to    location
1     2              3
2     2              3
3     3              3

myUsers
id    name
1     John
2     David
3     Sally

myLocation
id    name
1     SAT
2     DEN
3     AUS
```

Basically the end product should pull the "myTable" data and fill into a table (which I already know how to do) the name and location of each row/column so that it states something alongm the lines of

```
ID     Assigned To            Location
1      David                  SAT
```

Instead of

```
ID     Assigned To            Location
1      2                      2
```

Comment: You need to learn about [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s

Answer (score 1):

This should produce the expected result:

```
SELECT mt.id, mu.name, ml.name
FROM mytable mt JOINT myUsers mu ON mt.assigned_to = mu.id
JOIN myLocation ml ON mt.location = ml.id
```